# Workaround for needing an _id row for CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I found out in order for the Android CursorAdapter class to work I need a row _id.  Now, I have a specific naming scheme and do not want to change my id column (called ID) to _id for all the tables I need CursorAdapters for.  I think this will affect readability of some of my complex queries- plus "_id" is ugly :P.

I'm debating using custom "TableID as _id" select queries, but I like SQLiteDatabase's nice query methods and it doesn't look like they support renaming columns in the query.

It seems rather inflexible (and odd) to always require a specific table column name.  Is there a way to specify what column to use as the id column to the CursorAdapter?  Or maybe another workaround I haven't thought of?

Comment: +1 - `"_id" is ugly :P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternate solutions would be to either use a `CursorWrapper`, or use the `ProjectionMap` of a `ManagedQuery` to map your uid to_id.

Comment: CursorWrapper could work.  I'm not familiar with using managed queries, but a google search took me to the setProjectionMap method of SQLiteQueryBuilder which might do the trick...

Comment: ManagedQuery works with ContentProviders, which I implemented in my project as I am trying to learn as much as possible... ;) One more solution would be to create a view in your database that includes _id as one of the columns.

Comment: I didn't think of making a view.  Thanks for the many suggestions.  None are as simple as what I was looking for (dang you CursorAdapter!), but I guess that's life.  Thanks again.

Comment: I faced the same issue recently. I ended up downloading the source code for CursorAdapter and modifying it to take an index name in the constructor to use as the primary key index.

Answer (score 13):

There's no need to use a raw query, CursorWrapper, etc.  You can do exactly what you mentioned: when you specify the columns for your query, just specify "TableID as _id" as one of them.  Actually, instead of _id I would use BaseColumns._ID.  Something like this ought to work just fine:

```
static final String[] columns = new String[] {
    "TableID AS " + BaseColumns._ID,
    ...
};
```

And then pass that to whatever you're using to create your cursor (SQLiteDatabase, CursorLoader, etc.)

I would also recommend putting your column names into String constants that you can reference throughout your app, e.g. `MyDatabase.TABLE_ID`, so the above would be `MyDatabase.TABLE_ID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID`

Answer (score 11):

Your database doesn't need to have a column called '_id' but the CursorAdaptor does need to have one returned. You can do this with an alias (such as your "TableID as _id" idea) in a rawQuery.

An example is that I have a table with columns...

```
uid,name,number
```

To query this for a SimpleCursorAdapter (for example), I do this with a database `rawQuery`...

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT uid as _id,name,number FROM MY_TABLE");
```

This works fine and supplies the necessary '_id' column to SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: Yes, I was considering that, but I'd prefer to use the .query methods in the SQLiteDatabase class rather than .rawQuery.  If there's no other way, I'll just have to choose the lesser of two evils (renaming the column OR constructing my queries by hand and using rawQuery).  Are there any other methods besides .rawQuery that will allow me to rename columns?

Comment: @Emily: For my current app, I'd personally find renaming my DB columns as being the ultimate evil (especially as I'm mirroring a DB on a remote system) but obviously it will vary from dev to dev and app to app. On the point of using the SQLiteDatabase query methods, again a personal observation, but I've always used 'raw' SQL as I program with different languages and different platforms. Raw SQL is portable and I've also seen some truly horrible examples here on SO of people trying to perform complex queries using the SQLiteDatabase query methods.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, with some help from this post [sequential row numbers from query](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/sequential-row-numbers-from-query-td47370.html). It uses a generated _id field.  The advantage here is you don't need to mess with your schema and you get nice sequential _id values.

My code to load the Cursor was as follows:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
                 "SELECT * "
                +"FROM Sale "
                +"ORDER BY orderTime "
                , null);
```

I added the inner select, which requires an alias on the outer table name. (Note how **t2** is used in the inner select but is created in the outer select)

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT "
           +"(select COUNT(0) from Sale t1 where t1.orderTime <= t2.orderTime) as _id,t2.* "
           +"FROM Sale t2 "
           +"ORDER BY t2.orderTime "
            , null);
```